# Reactjs displays error users.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the following error in my React application:

> users.map is not a function

[I have tried many solutions posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419848/reactjs-this-props-data-map-is-not-a-function/35420569) but it does not seems to solve my issue.

I used the code below to submit a filename and it works fine. Here is my problem. Each time i click on submit button, i 
want to display a JSON data from the backend in a succession (For Instance If I submit form 3 times, I need to have 3 records of JSON data showed).

Here is the sample of JSON:

```js
{"filename":"macofile","message":"success","uid":"20"}
```

To this effect I have set the following line of code in the **Axios** Post response

```js
this.setState({
  users: res.data,
  loading: false,
});
```

I have also tried

```js
users: res
```

or

```js
users.push(res.data);
```

This is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios, { post } from "axios";

class FilePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: "",
      filename: "",
      loading: false,
      users: [],
      error: null
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  _handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //send it as form data
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("filename", this.state.filename);

    //alert(this.state.filename);

    this.setState({ loading: true }, () => {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost/apidb_react/up.php", formData)
        .then(res => {
          this.setState({
            users: res.data,
            loading: false
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err.message);
        });
    });
  }

  // handle form submission
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, users, error } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={e => this._handleSubmit(e)}>
          <b>filename:</b>
          <input
            tyle="text"
            className="form-control"
            value={this.state.filename}
            name="filename"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />

          <button
            className="submitButton"
            type="submit"
            onClick={e => this._handleSubmit(e)}
          >
            submit
          </button>
        </form>

        <React.Fragment>
          <h3>Display Data each time record is submitted</h3>

          {error ? <p>{error.message}</p> : null}

          {!loading ? (
            users.map(user => {
              const { filename, message, uid } = user;

              return (
                <div key={uid}>
                  <p>Userid: {uid}</p>
                  <p>File Name: {filename}</p>
                  <p>Message: {message}</p>
                  <hr />
                </div>
              );
            })
          ) : (
            <h3>Loading...</h3>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you just need to add `JSON.parse(res.data)`

Comment: What does your data look like if your write `console.log(res);` in the axios request callback?

Comment: Can you share your axios config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your res.data seems to be an object rather than an array -> `{"filename":"macofile","message":"success","uid":"20"}`. So, you will need to loop through the object by taking an array for eg:

```
Object.keys(users).map(key => console.log(users[key]))
```