# Error while passing props: Uncaught TypeError: billingItem.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this child component:

```
const TableExpandedRowItem = ({ dataTitle, rowValue, cellClassProp }) => (
  <div data-title={dataTitle} className={cellClassProp}>
    <p>{rowValue}</p>
  </div>
);
```

I am passing it to its parent to create an iteration:

```
const TableExpandedRowWrapper = ({ rowClassProp, billingItem }) => (
  <div className={rowClassProp}>
    {billingItem.map(key => (
      <div>
        <TableExpandedRowItem
          dataTitle={billingItem[key].description}
          rowValue={billingItem[key].description}
        />
        <TableExpandedRowItem
          dataTitle={billingItem[key].recurringFee}
          rowValue={billingItem[key].recurringFee}
        />
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: billingItem.map is not a function

Here is where I need to call it:

```
{rowExpanded.billingItems &&
  rowExpanded.billingItems.map(item =>
      rowExpanded.id === item.cancellationRequestId && (
        <div className="row" key={item.id}>
          // HERE
          <TableExpandedRowWrapper billingItem={item.billingItem} />

...
```

UPDATE:

If I call the component `TableExpandedRowItem` directly without a the wrapper component it works as it should:

```
{rowExpanded.billingItems &&
  rowExpanded.billingItems.map(item =>
      rowExpanded.id === item.cancellationRequestId && (
        <div className="row" key={item.id}>
          <TableExpandedRowItem
            dataTitle={item.billingItem.description}
            rowValue={item.billingItem.description}
          />
          <TableExpandedRowItem
            dataTitle={item.billingItem.recurringFee}
            rowValue={item.billingItem.recurringFee}
          />
        </div>
      ),
  )}
```

I want to take this to another component which is what I am attempting to do on `TableExpandedRowWrapper`:

```
       <div className="row" key={item.id}>
          <TableExpandedRowItem
            dataTitle={item.billingItem.description}
            rowValue={item.billingItem.description}
          />
          <TableExpandedRowItem
            dataTitle={item.billingItem.recurringFee}
            rowValue={item.billingItem.recurringFee}
          />
        </div>
```

So basically what I need is to put `TableExpandedRowItem` into a wrapper and call it as shown above.

Comment: this appears to be a duplicate of this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419848/reactjs-this-props-data-map-is-not-a-function/35420569

Comment: It is not a duplicate at all. That other ticket has an ajax call and everything. This is just passing down props from one component to other. @gabrielwr

Comment: Possibly billingItem is an object, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721168/render-object-properties-in-react/43721237#43721237

Comment: This is dumb, but from the naming of variables, `billingItem` doesn't sound like an array and thus it would make sense that `billingItem.map` might not be a function. Throw in a `console.log` in `TableExpandedRowWrapper` maybe and double check?

Comment: @TheUnnamed, I only say that it is a duplicate in that the root issue of both threads are the same: the prop being passed down is an object, not an array -- even though there are other things like ajax going on in the other post.

Comment: @AnandUndavia See the update I did to the post.